# Node-red create dynamic hyperlink on Dashboard

Tags: dashboard, node-red

I want to create a dynamic hyperlink on the dashboard in any way. I am reading a part of the URL from a textfile which works so far. Only the last part beyond the / shold be dynamic.

The URL should look like https://example.webpage.com/"dynamic part"

I am using the ui-template node.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I worked with href. Like :<div>
    <a href="http://example.com"><span>test</span></a>
</div>     But I dont know how to add my msg.payload

Comment: Please edit the question when asked to add more detail. Also which template node are you using? The Dashboard-ui template or the core template node?

Answer (score 0):

I think this [post](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/create-a-hyperlink-from-payload-on-dashboard/16532/5) will help you!